# How do you join (merge) dataframes by variable number of columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge, data.table

I am trying to left-join two data.frames by multiple columns. Except not all merging columns should be used depending on the rows of the tables.

Here is a reproducible example (the original tables are several million rows) :

```r
articles <- data.frame(article = paste0("article_", c(1,2,3,2,2,3)), index1 = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c"), index2 = c("i", "i", "j", NA, "j", "k"), index3 = c("tom", "lucy", NA, NA, NA, NA))
prices <- data.frame(index1 = c("a", "b", "c"), index2 = c("i", "i", "j"), index3 = c("tom", "lucy", "tom"), price = c(10, 20, 5))
```

So I have an "articles" table (left) that tells how to reconstruct the column "article" based on the 3 index columns. And a "price" table (right), which for each index gives us the according price :

```
    article    index1 index2 index3
1: article_1      a      i    tom
2: article_2      a      i   lucy
3: article_3      a      j   <NA>                    index1 index2 index3 price
4: article_2      b   <NA>   <NA>                 1:   a      i     tom     10                                     
5: article_2      c      j   <NA>                 2:   b      i     lucy    20
6: article_3      c      k   <NA>                 3:   c      j     tom     5
```

I simply want to left-join the two tables so that I can have the price of each article. Problem:

We can see that the "articles" table contains missing values when the information is not needed:

- when index1 == "b", we do not need index2 and index3 columns because when index1 == "b", the article is always 2.
- when index1 == "c", we do not need index3 because if index2 == "j", the article is always 2, and when index2 == "k", the article is always 3.

I insist that I can not complete missing values because we do not know in advance all the possible values of index2 and index3 columns.

So when I try to left-join (merge) them, I obtain the left table, whereas I would like to obtain the one on the right :

**data.frame**

```r
merging_columns <- c("index1", "index2", "index3")
merge(x = prices, y = articles, all.x = TRUE, by = merging_columns)[, c("price", "article")]

     article   price                  article    price
1:  article_1    10               1:  article_1    10
2:     <NA>      20               2:  article_2    20
3:     <NA>      5                3:  article_3    5
```

I can't reconstruct the article column for article_2 and article_3.
I would like the joining not to try to join by the merging columns **when** they contain missing values.

So, how do you join (merge) dataframes by variable number of columns in R ?

- data.frame, data.table, dplyr... answers are welcomed
- the "articles" table contains **NA** when the information is
  not needed but could be replace with anything if necessary

Comment: I think its a way easier if those NA values were to be replaced with something, like "-" for example, as it will make noise for merge operations for what I believe

Comment: I guess, as there is no unambiguous mapping between prices and articles, you need to take a step-wise approach: first, filter articles for index1 == b and do the join based on index1 only. Then filter for index1 == c and do the join based on index2, etc...

Comment: @JovanGeraldyCandra Yes we could replace NA with anything else. The results will be similar though with base merge() function.

Comment: @WolfgangArnold The problem is that this is a little example. The real data have > 1000 different realizations of the indexes variables.